# Having Rc<T>s in one module and Rc<RefCell<T>>s in another referencing the same data

Tags: data-structures, rust, interior-mutability

I have a data structure like this:

```
mod nodes {
    struct Node {
        predecessors: Vec<Rc<Node>>
    }
}
```

I obviously don't need mutability of the nodes in that module. I also don't have cyclic references here.

But I have another module, which contains nodes, where I need mutability:

```
pub mod network {
    mod nodes {...}

    struct Network {
        nodes: Vec<Vec<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>>
    }
}
```

I just can't figure out a way to create the `Rc<Node>`s for the nodes themselves together with the `Rc<RefCell<Node>>`s for the `Network`.

Do you have any idea on how to implement the immutability in the `nodes` module next to the mutable nodes in the `network` module?

Or is there no other way than to declare the references to the predecessor nodes inside the `Node` struct as `Rc<RefCell<Node>>`, even though I don't need mutability here (I would like to avoid that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust has [single ownership](https://www.geekabyte.io/2020/02/rust-ownership-rules.html). If a `Node` is owned by a `RefCell`, it cannot also be owned by a different `Rc` at the same time.

When a `Node` can be modified in one place via `RefCell`, these changes cannot be allowed to show up elsewhere in `Rc<Node>`. This would violate immutability of `Rc<Node>`.

Also note that `Node` is a struct value, not a pointer to an object. There's no extra layer of indirection that would even make it possible to share it between `RefCell` and other `Rc`. Its data is copied and inlined in its container.

- Consider using `Rc<RefCell<Node>>` in both places. If the same data is used in both places, it has to uphold all guarantees in both places, even if you're not taking advantage of that.
- If you're not using both types at the same time, you can convert from one type to another by deconstructing it ([`into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.into_inner), [`try_unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.try_unwrap)) and constructing the other type again. This conversion is not free, because physical memory layout of these types is different.
- If you only sometimes need mutability, `Rc` has [`make_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.make_mut) that works without `RefCell`. And `RefCell` has a zero-cost [`get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.get_mut) if you already have a mutable access to it, so you might be able to reduce their overhead in specific cases.